# Best method for checking integrity of 50 GiB files?

Tags: integrity

I'm making backups of compressed data (using ZPAQ), some compressed archives are large (50 GiB)

I was just going to use `sha3sum -a 512`, for example:

```
sha3sum -a 512 "Total_DOS_Collection-RELEASE#17-[1981-1995].zpaq"
```

Then storing the value and later periodically checking if the value of the backup is still the same

Then I started wondering if there would be a better/safer/more appropriate/effective method...

Comment: Could you define what is better, safer, /more appropriate/effective method for you? Where do you store these files? SHA3 is not a recovery for errors. You may need RAID or multiple backups, that is out of CSE.

Comment: sha3 will be slow as hell, use blake2 in a tree hash mode

Comment: I know SHA3 is not a recovery for errors, the idea is me being aware when the file has somehow become corrupted, by comparing the actual SHA3-512 to the SHA3-512 of the original file

Comment: The best method in my opinion, would be one that allows me to know if the file has become corrupt or not, just that. I think knowing the original SHA3-512 sum of a file would be enough for this, I'm looking for confirmation here. If there would be any kind of modification of the compressed archive (partial corruption, for example), the SHA3-512 sum would be different, right? And if no modification had been done to the compressed archived, the SHA3-512 would always be the same, right?

Comment: Tree hashing. Either functions with native support like Blake2 or a generalized method like Merkle tree hashes. The point of tree hashing is to enable parallelism (faster hashing) + ability to detect exactly which sections have been modified.

Comment: Just use ZFS. Fun fact, it uses SHA-256 and tree hashing. It stores the hashes apart from the data, which makes it less prone to random changes within sectors of data.

Comment: What is your threat model?  Why a collision-resistant hash instead of a CRC, which has better error-detection capacity against independent random bit flips?  What will you do if you detect an error?

Comment: Have no threat model, just want to store backups of important data and be able to notice if eventually there is corruption of any kind

Thought checking if the SHA3-512 sum of a given file was still the same or not would be a goood solution to my problem, was I wrong and should use crc32 instead?

If I detect corruption on, for example, a backup on a Blu-Ray Disc, I would grab another copy of a given backup which is still intact and burn a new Blu-Ray Disc. My backups consists of ZPAQ compressed archives on the cloud, on local hdds (EXT4) and Blu-Ray Discs

Comment: @Natanael  What tool would you recommend in Linux for tree hashing?

Comment: It would appear that [bt2sum](https://github.com/s3git/bt2sum) is a ready-made tool that computes the aforementioned blake2 tree hash using good defaults (namely using the number of CPU cores for parallel processing), if you feel standard `b2sum` is too slow, give this a try (and only turn to `b2sum` if the sha3 utility is too slow for you).

Answer (score 1):

Tree hashing would be a natural way to do it.

However, the data still needs to be read. And in practice the hash computation time is negligible compared to I/O, even with a fast SSD.

So, just use a standard hash function. SHA-3 is slow in software, so you'd better opt for BLAKE2.

Comment: Dunno, SSD's have become pretty fast of late. I've got an Intel 660p which runs at 1.8 GB/s at full speed. Sure, hashes can be fast, but at those speeds you'll have to make sure that you've got the right implementation at the very least.